# Emit Warning About possible null Property

Tags: c#, c#-7.3

Is it possible to have a warning emitted when trying to used a possibly null property in C# 7.3?  Or better yet, can I have the compiler emit an error instead?

```
class MyParentClass {
  public MyChildClass ChildClass {get; set;}
}

class MyChildClass {
  public int Total {get; set;}
}

public void SomeFunction() {
  MyParentClass mpc = new MyParentClass();
  # It would be nice to have a warning emitted about ChildClass being possibly null.
  mpc.ChildClass.Total = 100;
}
```

Comment: But it is initialized - to `null`, which is the default value for reference types.

Comment: @UnholySheep, I corrected my question to reflect your input.

Comment: `if ( mpc.ChildClass == null ) ...`

Comment: @OlivierRogier, I would like a warning or error to automatically be emitted so the developer would automatically be informed that they need to add a null check.  The code will still compile if they omit the null check, leading to a runtime exception.

Comment: There is not such feature. The coder is responsible to create all instance or check if null.

Comment: You'll need C# 8.

Comment: Why C# 8 needed?

Comment: @OlivierRogier, C# 8 brings [non-nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references).

Answer (score 1):

You can give your property the [`[CanBeNull]`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Code_Annotation_Attributes.html#CanBeNullAttribute) attribute from `JetBrains.Annotations`. A library like ReSharper can see this and raise a warning:

> Indicates that the value of the marked element could be `null` sometimes, so checking for `null` is required before its usage.